# Using INSERT INTO SELECT & VALUES TOGETHER

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm having trouble using `INSERT INTO` with values from another table and one value from a variable.

Using only MySQL, this query worked perfectly:

```
INSERT INTO insumos_da_venda (vendacod, insumocod, nome, quantidade, unidmedida, preco) `
SELECT '11' AS vendacod
       , cod
       , nome
       , quantidade
       , unidmedida
       , preco 
FROM insumos_da_venda_temp
```

But when I try to use this inside c# code, it's transforming anything that I put where '11' is into '1'.

Doesn't matter if its a variable, a random value, or even if its blank, it'll always be '1' when I execute the command

Here's the c# code:

```
string insertInsumosVenda = "INSERT INTO insumos_da_venda (vendacod, insumocod, nome, quantidade, unidmedida, preco) 
SELECT '" + vendacod + "' AS vendacod
       , cod
       , nome
       , quantidade
       , unidmedida
       , preco 
FROM insumos_da_venda_temp;";

MySqlCommand insertInsumosVendaCmd = new MySqlCommand(insertInsumosVenda, BDconnection);

reader = insertInsumosVendaCmd.ExecuteReader();

while (reader.Read()) { }

reader.Close();
```

Here, the variable 'vendacod' can be any value from 0 to 99999

vendacod column is int(5) but I've also tried changing it to varchar and still didn't work.

I've seen some similar questions but none worked for me, I have no idea why.

Edit1:

> You should be using parameterized queries. Your code is vulnerable to
> SQL Injection

I know its a pretty poorly written code, I'm making this program only for study purposes and for now I'm only studying c#, I'll upgrade my MySQL skills after, thanks for the tips

> vendacod column is int(5) but I've also tried changing it to varchar
> and still didn't work - can't quite believe that C# can't handle the
> display formatter, and I can't quite believe that making it a varchar
> failed (unless it was a varchar(1) and you somehow didn't get a
> truncation error?) - can you show some screenshots of it "not working"
> as a varchar?

While taking screenshots I just realized something: it's not always '1', it's getting the value of the first column of "insumos_da_venda_temp" which is not even in the code, so I have no idea what's happening

here are some screenshots:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/JRfNf.jpg

Edit2:

3 Days working this out and I finally made it work.

I trusted @CaiusJard, he said it should be working then I decided to find any other reason why it wasn't working.

truth is, 100% my mistake, what I was doing was: transfering everything OUT of "insumos_da_venda_temp" tab then trying to insert into "insumos_da_venda" tab from there, and since it had nothing, i think something went crazy and it was inserting data that wasn't even there.

Thank you all for responding, every single one of you guys helped me a lot, not only on this problem but also by teaching me some mysql

Comment: use ExecuteScalar instead of Executereader

Comment: You should be using parameterized queries. Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection. https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/a20beb/why-should-always-use-the-parameterized-query-to-avoid-sql-i/

Comment: 1) Don't write SQLs like that, it leads to [this](https://www.vice.com/en/article/xygg9w/vtech-hacker-explains-why-he-hacked-the-toy-company). 2) if the column is an int, why are you putting the value in string delimiters `'` ?

Comment: @nabuchodonossor no; DML is ExecuteNonQuery, not ExecuteScalar (which is for retrieving resultsets of size 1x1)

Comment: *vendacod column is int(5) but i've also tried changing it to varchar and still didn't work* - can't quite believe that C# can't handle the display formatter, and I can't quite believe that making it a varchar failed (unless it was a varchar(1) and you somehow didn't get a truncation error?) - can you show some screenshots of it "not working" as a varchar?

Comment: Is vendacod an autoincrement primary key? Can you show us create table insumos_da_venda  script?

Comment: @Serge it's not, i just posted some screenshots, i'm using localhost/phpmyadmin, so i think its even easier for you to see that (image 3)

Comment: @CaiusJard just posted some screenshots.

Comment: Is it just me or are those screenshots blurry to the point of being unreadable?

Comment: @CaiusJard they're 100% fine here, from both my pc and smartphone

Comment: @CaiusJard: sure, you are correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really dont know why you are having that problem but you could try using MySqlParameter,
You can read more about it here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-net/8.0/html/P_MySql_Data_MySqlClient_MySqlCommand_Parameters.htm.

Anyway the implementation would be like this:

```
  MySqlParameter p1= new MySqlParameter("@vendacod",vendacod);
    
    string insertInsumosVenda = "INSERT INTO insumos_da_venda (vendacod, insumocod, nome, quantidade, unidmedida, preco) 
    SELECT @vendacod AS vendacod
           , cod
           , nome
           , quantidade
           , unidmedida
           , preco 
    FROM insumos_da_venda_temp;";
    
    MySqlCommand insertInsumosVendaCmd = new MySqlCommand(insertInsumosVenda, BDconnection);
    
    insertInsumosVendaCmd.Parameters.Add(p1);
    
   InsertInsumosVendaCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Didn't work, While taking screenshots i just realized something: it's not always '1', it's getting the value of the first column of "insumos_da_venda_temp" wich is not even in the code, so i have no idea whats happening

Comment: You've marked this as the answer, but it's not really clear how it is the answer. If you solved it in some other way, post your own answer rather than marking an existing one. If anything, Serge's is the better answer because this one still has all that odd use of ExecuteReader to run a query that doesn't return any results..

Answer (score 1):

you are trying to insert vendacod  as a string, but it is an integer columnt ( int(5) ). Try to add vendacod  as an integer parameter

```
string insertInsumosVenda = "INSERT INTO insumos_da_venda (vendacod, insumocod, nome, quantidade, unidmedida, preco) 
SELECT @vendacod AS vendacod
       , cod
       , nome
       , quantidade
       , unidmedida
       , preco 
        FROM insumos_da_venda_temp;";

    var cmd = new MySqlCommand(insertInsumosVenda, BDconnection);
   cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
     cmd.Parameters.Add("@vendacod", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = vendacod;
    cmd.conection.Open();
   var result= cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    cmd.connection.Close();
```